# CakePHP : Multiselect input data insert into database

Tags: php, cakephp

My Multiselect input code is

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Dispensary.role.',array('options'=>$dispensary_users,'class'=>'form-control dispensary_users_dd','label'=>false,'style'=>'width:300px;','empty'=>'Select Users'));
?>
```

and generated html code :

```
<select name="data[Dispensary][role][]" class="form-control dispensary_users_dd" style="width: 300px; display: none;" id="DispensaryRole">
  <option value="">Select Users</option>
  <option value="9">Yashobanta</option>
  <option value="80">Yash</option>
  <option value="83">Ramesh</option>
</select>
```

But when I select all users, and `print_r($this->data);`
returns last selected input.
But I want all.

Comment: Suggestion - Learn basic html along with php especially form attributes, this will help you with such common things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot to add `multiple => true`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how that thing with `$this->Form->input(...);` works, because it's not important. You can select only one opinion without `multiple` attribute.

Example by w3schools.org:

```
<select name="cars" multiple>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

For saving the multiple select value in database, store the array using implode function.

In controller:

```
if (!empty($this->data)) {
    $this->data['Category']['name'] = implode(",",$this->data['Category']['name']);
       $this->Category->create();
       $this->Category->save($this->data);
}
```

Hope it's help :)